# What is more efficient: single node or multi node loading with Firebase/AngularJS 1.x

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have one page where I need to load multiple nodes from the Firebase Real-Time Database. The structure is as follows:

```
/overview/$date/list
/overview/$date/alerts
/overview/$date/other
```

What is more efficient when using AngularJS 1.x:

- load `overview/$date` once
- or creating multiple functions and loading per node:

  - load `/overview/$date/list`
  - load `/overview/$date/alerts`
  - load `/overview/$date/other`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $date only contains those same three children, and you want all the children all the time, you will probably not measure much of a difference between the two.  The single query may be a tad faster.  But if you have other children under it that you don't want to read, the single query might be slower, as it's loading more data than you need.

Comment: Lets assume that we need to load all the data (with their children). Then there will be no difference? How about adding it to the scope in AngularJS: scope.data = result or is it better scope.list = result['list'] etc?

Comment: I didn't say "no difference" - I said not much of a difference.  It's an optimization that might not be measurable.  I don't think scope has anything to do with it.  If you have a different question about scope, please ask it as a separate question.